# Qt3D SceneLoader issue with alpha materials

Tags: qt, qt3d

I'm using SceneLoader to load an obj + mtl model which has some materials with alpha. Geometry data is loaded correctly but **materials with transparency are rendered fully opaque**.

this the definition of the material shown opaque:

```
newmtl Glass
Ka 0.5000 0.5000 0.5000
Kd 0.5000 0.5000 0.5000
Ks 0.5000 0.5000 0.5000
Tf 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
d 0.5000
illum 4
```

Is this a Qt bug or a bad assimp parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that using SceneLoader with an ".obj" file doesn't parse transparency parameters quite well. 
The solution to my problem was using the "**qgltf**" application so I could convert my model to gltf format (besides it has lower loading times). Then edit the generated qgltf file by adding the parameter "transparency" to the corresponding material.